# Change class of radio button on check with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do a rating system with smiley face from Font Awesome like this

```js
$('input[type=radio][name=smiley]').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    console.log(this.value);
    $(this).removeClass('fa-regular');
    $(this).addClass('fa-solid');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('fa-solid');
    $(this).addClass('fa-regular');
  }
});
```

```css
form#smileys input[type="radio"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: border 0.2s ease;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  margin: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

form#smileys input[type="radio"]:hover,
form#smileys input[type="radio"]:checked {
  filter: grayscale(0);
}

form#smileys input[type="radio"]:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form id="smileys">
  <input type="radio" name="smiley" id="frown" value="frown" class="fa-face-frown fa-2xl fa-regular">
  <input type="radio" name="smiley" id="eye-roll" value="eye-roll" class="fa-regular fa-face-rolling-eyes fa-2xl">
  <input type="radio" name="smiley" id="neutral" value="neutral" class="fa-regular fa-face-meh fa-2xl">
  <input type="radio" name="smiley" id="smile-wink" value="smile-wink" class="fa-regular fa-face-smile-wink fa-2xl">
  <input type="radio" name="smiley" id="happy" value="happy" class="fa-regular fa-face-laugh-beam fa-2xl">
</form>
```

So far the icon change on check but will not change back when I check another radio. I'm aware of the problem that is $(this) will only check the current checked radio but I'm struggling to find a different fix than changing the other 4 back by ids everytime a radio is checked which is very inefficient. Any recommendations on how should I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `fa-solid` class and add `fa-regular` class to sibling not the clicked element. Also you don't need to check checked because it is always checked on click element since it is radio button. And remove `fa-regular` and add `fa-solid` class on current element. Check the following code sample.

```js
$('input[type=radio][name=smiley]').change(function() {
  $(this).siblings("input").removeClass('fa-solid').addClass('fa-regular');
  $(this).removeClass('fa-regular').addClass('fa-solid');
});
```

```css
form#smileys input[type="radio"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: border 0.2s ease;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  margin: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

form#smileys input[type="radio"]:hover,
form#smileys input[type="radio"]:checked {
  filter: grayscale(0);
}

form#smileys input[type="radio"]:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form id="smileys">
  <input type="radio" name="smiley" id="frown" value="frown" class="fa-face-frown fa-2xl fa-regular">
  <input type="radio" name="smiley" id="eye-roll" value="eye-roll" class="fa-regular fa-face-rolling-eyes fa-2xl">
  <input type="radio" name="smiley" id="neutral" value="neutral" class="fa-regular fa-face-meh fa-2xl">
  <input type="radio" name="smiley" id="smile-wink" value="smile-wink" class="fa-regular fa-face-smile-wink fa-2xl">
  <input type="radio" name="smiley" id="happy" value="happy" class="fa-regular fa-face-laugh-beam fa-2xl">
</form>
```